# How do I link directories in python (Linux cmd ln -s equivalent)?

Tags: python, linux, ln

I'm translating Linux commands to a python script. How would I perform the Linux command 'ln -s'

CMD:

```
    ln -s /users/me/link_file hello
```

I want to link 'hello' to 'link_file' in python

Thanks!

Comment: If you actually want to "perform the Linux command", see the `subprocess` module. If you want to create a symlink in the same way the Linux command does, see the `os` or `pathlib` module.

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: Just want to make sure... Can't try it without knowing for sure because the environment is delicate.

Comment: I think it is good to find the simple answer here on stackoverflow. The two questions are not the same...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`os.symlink()` is the provided function for creating symlinks. They are created as such:

```
import os
os.symlink(src,dst)
```

Where `src` and `dst` are the paths.

See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink) for more info.

Comment: "Create a symbolic link pointing to src named dst."

Comment: The answer provided doesn't work if provided src path is relative - it creates broken link. Use following instead:

    import os
    os.symlink(os.path.abspath(src), dst)